# If a sequence of independent random variables converges almost surely to a random variable, then that limit is almost surely a constant

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables converging almost surely to a random variable $X$. Then how to show that $X$ is almost surely a constant ?

I think I somehow have to apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma for independent events, but I don't know how.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $X_n \to X$ almost surely. Thus if $\Omega_0 = \{X_n \to X\}$ then $\mathbb P(\Omega_0) = 1$. Then for any fixed $c \in \mathbb R$
$$ \Omega_0 \cap \{X < c\} = \Omega_0 \cap\{X_n < c\ \text{infinitely often}\}$$
Then apply Borel-Cantelli to justify that $\{X_n < c\ \text{infinitely often}\}$ happens with probability either 0 or 1, thus
$$\mathbb P(X < c) = \mathbb P(\Omega_0 \cap \{X < c\}) = \mathbb P(\Omega _0\cap \{X_n < c\ \text{i.o.}\}) = \mathbb P(\text{$X_n < c$ i.o.})$$ and will equal 0 or 1. Use this to deduce that $X$ is almost surely constant.

Comment: the exercise is to a chapter where only Borel-Cantelli lemmas, Fatou's lemma, MCT, DCT are given ... no Kolmogorov 0-1 law ...

Comment: You could try proving the 0-1 law yourself, but the proof is unrelated to the Borel-Cantelli lemmas, Fatou's lemma or any of the convergence theorems.

Comment: I am using the book; Knowing the Odds: An Introduction to Probability , by John B. Walsh; 2012 edition; page 129, Problem 4.23

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out

Comment: I don't think your equality is correct ... could you elaborate a bit more please ?

Comment: I should be clearer, the sets are equal up to null sets, i.e. their symmetric difference has measure 0. In particular they will have the same measure. I've edited my answer to be clearer.