# Prove if $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of independent r.v. and converges to $X$ in probability, then $X$ is a constant almost surely.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Prove that if $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of independent random variables and converges to $X$ in probability, then $X$ is a constant almost surely.

My attempt:
To prove that $X$ is a constant a.s., it suffices to show that $\mathbb{P}(X<x)=0 \text{ or } 1$. 
Notice that $X_n\xrightarrow[]{\mathbb{P}}X$ implies $X_n\xrightarrow[]{D}X$. Thus, $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq x)\leq\mathbb{P}(\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\{X_n\leq x\}).$ 
By Borel's 0-1 law, we have $\mathbb{P}(\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\{X_n\leq x\})=0\text{ or } 1$ .
Similarly, $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)\geq\mathbb{P}(\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\{X_n\leq x\})=0\text{ or }1.$ 
I notice that if both $\mathbb{P}(\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\{X_n\leq x\})$ and $\mathbb{P}(\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\{X_n\leq x\})$ always have the same value(0 or 1), then we can prove that $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=0 \text{ or }1$. But somehow I find it very hard to prove. Is there something I have not thought of?

Edit:
OK, I have figured it out. In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986560/if-a-sequence-of-independent-random-variables-converges-almost-surely-to-a-rando?rq=1), we have the conclusion for convergence almost surely. As for convergence in probability, we can always find its subsequence that convergences almost surely to $X$. Then, we can apply the conclusion for convergence almost surely.